# AWS Lambda Function Timing out while modifying volume

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a simple aws lambda js function that when I pass region, volumeid and volumetype it changes the volume type of the volume with that ID.

Anyway, whenever I try to test the function passing all the parameters, I get the function timing out after 3000ms, but I can't understand why...

Can somebody help me?

Many thanks in advance!

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: event.instanceRegion });

ec2.ModifyVolume({ VolumeId: [event.volumeId] , VolumeType: [event.VolumeType] });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question, you need to annotate your code block with markdown using backticks (`). For more help formatting your answer, check out [this link(https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Does it work successfully if you increase the timeout? (eg 60 seconds) This is just to determine the cause of the issue.